# Элемент формы для выбора из многомерного массива

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Есть справочник с марками и моделями и др.. в формате xml вот пример: 
 https://autoload.avito.ru/format/truck_catalog.xml

Этот Xml файл я преобразовываю в многомерный массив плагином https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml

Необходимо как-то реализовать для пользователя выбор из этого справочника. Пока есть вариант с помощью несколько select'ов но пока не знаю как это реализовать. Подскажите может есть какие либо готовый решения в виде плагинов.

Comment: Обратите внимание на поиск в XML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696545/simplexml-get-node-child-based-on-attribute

Comment: Проблема не в преобразовании xml а в предоставление возможность выбора из этих данных. Т.е. как реализовать интерфейс приложение чтобы пользователь выбирал данные которые получаются из xml файл

Comment: Ну так выведите их в select на страницу и через POST/GET отправляйте ключ, который будете искать уже как вам надо.